# Why do we need to add SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege before using ExitWindowsEx

Tags: winapi

Before we can use the `ExitWindowsEx` function for shutting down the computer, we must add the `SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME` privilege to the process like this:

```
HANDLE hToken = NULL;
LUID luid;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
LookupPrivilegeValue(L"", SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, &luid);
TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
bRet = AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(tp), NULL, 0);

ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT, 0);
```

This works perfectly fine.

I know that this is by design, but I don't understand what's the motivation of Microsoft for deciding that a privilege must be enabled before the `ExitWindowsEx` function can be used. It's obviously not designed to prevent a process from rebooting the computer, because all it needs to do for rebooting is adding the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME to the process and call `ExitWindowsEx`.

The Windows developpment term could have put the code above directly into the `ExitWindowsEx` function.

Comment: -1. You misunderstand whole point. You must enable privilege, so if you dont have this privilege, you dont shutdown system.

Comment: @user2120666: no, I perfectly **did** understood the whole point, I know that the privilege must be enabled, this is BTW written in the Microsoft documentation and BTW my code above **does** enable the needed privilege. Read my question again. The question is all about why Microsoft decided thats soome privilege must be enabled before `ExitWindowsEx` can be used.

Comment: Because this is whole point of privilegies.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to add it (you can't add a privilege to your current token), you need to *enable* it.

Most privileges are disabled by default, probably to avoid an accidental use (just like the read-only attribute on files). There's no need to run around with the privilege enabled at all times, and having the `ExitWindowsEx` function enable it by itself would break consistency with other privilege-dependent functions.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll wait a couple of days to get more answers before I'll accept your answer (or another possibly better one).

Comment: Avoid "accidental use" is correct. It is no security barrier, if the privilege is not enabled since it can be enabled easily. So is it more like a "convenience" for programmers to avoid calling a "system" function by accident (usually if one hasn't read the docs).