# Java JNA call to function "InitiateSystemShutdown" in dll Advapi32 don't work

Tags: java, dll, jna

I have this call to the function "InitiateSystemShutdown" of the Advapi32 dll with java jna but it didn't work:

```
public interface JNAApiInterface extends StdCallLibrary {

    JNAApiInterface INSTANCE = (JNAApiInterface) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", JNAApiInterface.class);

    public boolean InitiateSystemShutdown(String machine, String message, short timeout, boolean forceAppClose, boolean rebootAfterShutdown);

}



public class JNABucket {
     public static void main(String args[]) {

          System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\Windows\\System32");
          JNAApiInterface jnaLib = JNAApiInterface.INSTANCE;

          jnaLib.InitiateSystemShutdown(null, null, (short)0, true, true);
     }
}
```

The error is:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up 
    function 'InitiateSystemShutdown': No se encontró el proceso especificado.
    at com.sun.jna.Function.<init>(Function.java:179)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:430)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getFunction(NativeLibrary.java:410)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:205)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.InitiateSystemShutdown(Unknown Source)
    at es.tecnocom.pruebas.JNABucket.main(JNABucket.java:9)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: Changing the method call to "InitiateSystemShutdownExW" works, but return false and not restarts system.

Answer (score 2):

If after changing the funcion to "InitiateSystemShutdownA" or "InitiateSystemShutdownW" still isn't working, it's probably a permissions issue, as @cubrr suggested.

Try adding this:

```
    HANDLEByReference hToken = new HANDLEByReference();
    LUID luid = new LUID();
    Advapi32.INSTANCE.OpenProcessToken(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcess(), WinNT.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, hToken);
    Advapi32.INSTANCE.LookupPrivilegeValue("", WinNT.SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, luid);
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp = new TOKEN_PRIVILEGES(1);
    tp.Privileges[0] = new LUID_AND_ATTRIBUTES(luid, new DWORD(WinNT.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED));
    Advapi32.INSTANCE.AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken.getValue(), false, tp, tp.size(), null, new IntByReference());
```

just before this call to the function:

```
jnaLib.InitiateSystemShutdown(null, null, (short)0, true, true);
```

Comment: @rjaraba Be sure to accept this answer by clicking on the checkbox :)

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the documentation page for [`InitiateSystemShutdown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873(v=vs.85).aspx), you'll notice at the bottom that the actual function names are `InitiateSystemShutdownW` (Unicode) and `InitiateSystemShutdownA` (ANSI). Most (all?) WinAPI functions which deal with strings are defined as preprocessor symbols which resolve to either the *A or *W ending function, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined at compile time.

Example from [**Working with Strings**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextW
#else
#define SetWindowText  SetWindowTextA
#endif
```

Rename your function to `InitiateSystemShutdownA` or `InitiateSystemShutdownW`, depending on which encoding you want to use. I've personally always used the ANSI variants, so I don't know if you need to specify the Unicode encoding manually if you go with the *W variant.

```
public interface JNAApiInterface extends StdCallLibrary {

    JNAApiInterface INSTANCE = (JNAApiInterface) Native.loadLibrary("Advapi32", JNAApiInterface.class);

    public boolean InitiateSystemShutdownA(String machine, String message, short timeout, boolean forceAppClose, boolean rebootAfterShutdown);
}
```

Notice also that you need certain privileges to restart a computer. Excerpt from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873(v=vs.85).aspx):

> To shut down the local computer, the calling thread must have the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege. To shut down a remote computer, the calling thread must have the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on the remote computer. By default, users can enable the SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on the computer they are logged onto, and administrators can enable the SE_REMOTE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege on remote computers. For more information, see Running with Special Privileges.
>
> Common reasons for failure include an invalid or inaccessible computer name or insufficient privilege. The error ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IN_PROGRESS is returned if a shutdown is already in progress on the specified computer. The error ERROR_NOT_READY can be returned if fast-user switching is enabled but no user is logged on.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my function to "InitiateSystemShutdownA" and now it  doesn't throws an exception but it returns "false" and don't restart the system. I don't know why it is not working.

Comment: @rjaraba What is the value of `Native.getLastError()` after the call? Notice also my recent addition.

Comment: @rjaraba Please try searching. [*How to Shut Down the System*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376871(v=vs.85).aspx) and [*Why do we need to add SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME privilege before using ExitWindowsEx*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634582/why-do-we-need-to-add-se-shutdown-name-privilege-before-using-exitwindowsex)

Comment: The result of the "Native.getLastError" is 5:

Error code 5 stands for "Access is Denied". You should check your user's access rights.
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED  
5 (0x5)  
Access is denied.